# ADT app not working at all WHY?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I created a simply app in eclipse for android but app doesnt working at all, its stopped right away when I launched it, even in emulator the same, there are not any errors in eclipse showed. Here is my Error LOG from emulator..Can you help me to solve it?

```
04-15 15:22:17.005: D/AndroidRuntime(1834): Shutting down VM
04-15 15:22:17.005: W/dalvikvm(1834): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a98ba8)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834): Process: com.munkodevelopment.wtffaktat, PID: 1834
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.munkodevelopment.wtffaktat/com.munkodevelopment.wtffaktat.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at com.munkodevelopment.wtffaktat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-15 15:22:17.095: E/AndroidRuntime(1834):  ... 11 more
04-15 15:22:43.735: I/Process(1834): Sending signal. PID: 1834 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Check Null pointer error `line no.25` in `MainActivity.java` class

Comment: Line 25 is this one; dont see nothing bad there

pushme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Answer (score 0):

when your launcher activity opening then onCreate() method is called, and at the time of activity initializing there is any nullpointer exception. this is why activity crashing before opening. check this at:

onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)

in onCreate() method in MainActivity.java at line no 25

Comment: Im new in developing, dont get it ... So I have to add something on my line 25 in MainActivity.Java? Couse there is :
pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: if you can provide some code from your onCreate method including line 25 of MainActivity hopefully i can help you more.

Comment: pushMe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
  {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
    //do somthing
   }
  });    where pushMe is a Button and OnClickListener is a callback Interface. hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Here:
Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  Button pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  
  pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textOne.setText("Testuju");
   }
  });
  

  if (savedInstanceState == null)

Comment: your code is looking correct, tell me the code at line 25. and recheck your tomcat log are you geting some exception or same exception what you have explained in your question?

Comment: My line 25 is :pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: add a break point on start of onCreate method then start your app in debug mode then check is your pushMe button is null or you getting some other object null on that you trying to perform some action.

Comment: pushME is probably null.  Post your code by editing it into your question, not as a comment.